# Search in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On pageload I want to show all fields in the `repeater control` and on typing licenseid in the textbox I want to show that specific licenceid details.

If I place below code in the datasource of repeater the first one is not working. In the second one I placed a `textbox` and set its value to `0` on pageload. It is working. But I want both to be working.

```
 SELECT * FROM License WHERE (0 = @selectAll OR LicenseID=@LicenseID) -> Not working 

 SELECT * FROM License WHERE (0 = @selectAll ) ->working

 SELECT * FROM License WHERE (LicenseID=@LicenseID)-> working
```

Binding Code

```
 Protected Sub BindRepeater()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from License", con)

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

        con.Open()

     End If

     Dim ds As New DataSet()

     Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

     adp.Fill(ds)



     Repeater1.DataBind()

     con.Close()

 End Sub
```

Comment: please post your binding code..

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub BindRepeater(int licenseID)

string qry = "Select * from License WHERE 1=1";
if(licenseID>0) qry += " AND LicenseID=" + licenseID.ToString();

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(qry, con)

If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

    con.Open()

 End If

 Dim ds As New DataSet()

 Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

 adp.Fill(ds)



 Repeater1.DataBind()

 con.Close()
```

End Sub